# Is there a quick way to find this matrix A?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find a matrix $\mathbf A$ such that $x^2 + 4y^2 + 9z^2 + 4xy - 6xz = 1$ can be written as

$$\begin{bmatrix}x&y&z\end{bmatrix}\mathbf A\begin{bmatrix}x&y&z\end{bmatrix}^\top = 1$$

Is there a quick way to do this? I can tell $\mathbf A$ is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & x_{12} & x_{13}\\
    x_{21} &4 & x_{23}\\
    x_{31} & x_{32} & 9
\end{bmatrix}$$

But I need to guess the other elements. Is there a quick way to solve this?

Comment: watch this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0yEiCV-xEWQ

Comment: Multiply it out once, and compare terms. No need to guess.

Comment: You can choose your matrix to be symmetric. In that case, divide coefficients of $xy,xz$ and $yz$ terms by $2$ to obtain the $x_{12},x_{13}$ and $x_{23}$ entries respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let consider

- $x_{12}=x_{21}=2$
- $x_{13}=x_{31}=-3$
- $x_{23}=x_{32}=0$

and in general

$$ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 + 2dxy+2exz+2fyz\implies  A=\begin{bmatrix}
    a & d & e\\
    d & b & f\\
    e & f & c
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

It' rather simple: it is the symmetric matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & -3\\
    2 & 4 & 0\\
    -3 & 0 & 9
\end{bmatrix},$$
where the coefficients $a_{ij}$  are half the coefficients of $x_ix_j$ in the quadratic form.